# Exclude a form from AJAX submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to submit two forms located inside the div #cart-container.

There is a third form which I dont want to submit via AJAX inside this div.

I have tried to just target the forms, but for some reason the only way I have been able to get the code to work is by calling the following code:

```
$('#cart-container').on('submit','form',function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            $('#purchase-submissions, .cart').fadeTo('fast', 0.3);
        },
        success: cart
    }); 
    return false; 
});

function cart() {
    var path = '/enter/embed-cart';
    $('#cart-container').load(path, function() {
        $('#purchase-submissions, .cart').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }); 
}
```

If I target just the two forms on this row, like this it only calls AJAX once.

```
$('#add_cart_form, #update_form').on('submit',function() {
```

Can anyone tell me how I can exclude the one form from the call?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#cart-container').on('submit', 'form', function (event) {
    if (event.target.id == 'formID') return;
    // Your ajax call code here
});
```

Here, `formID` is the ID of the form you want to Exclude from AJAX submission.

Also, you can try to target the two forms in this way:

```
$('#cart-container').on('submit','#add_cart_form, #update_form',function() {
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, didn't realise that was possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing -> on('submit','form',function(){ whatever })

Understand the arguments you are passing

1. 'submit' -> event
2. 'form' -> Selesctor for the target elements
3. function(){ whatever } -> function to call when this event occues on the selected elemtns.

The problem is with your selector.. you are targeting all forms by providing 'form'.. please provide a less generalized selector.

Example  : if you have something like this

```
<div id="form-div">
    <form></form>
    <form></form>
    <form></form>
</div>
```

then

```
on('submit','#form-div:nth-child(1), #form-div:nth-child(2)',function(){ whatever })
```